# Laravel session are not collectly filled

Tags: php, laravel, session

I get stucked with following: I have switcher in my laravel application which request to Controller which actually does setting session parameters passed in form input and returns `back()` responce. Issue is that sometime it got filled incorrectly and mixing two variables.

I have whi variables `account_id` and `building_id` (last is calculated based on `account_id`) and in that case `building_id` becomes equal to `account_id` and leads to exception.

Code for detail (Controller):

```
public function switchHeaders(Request $request) {

    $account = Account::find($request->get('account_id'));

    if ($request->has('account_id') && $account !== null) {

        session([
            'account_id'    => $account->id,
            'building_id'   => $account->building_id,
        ]);
    } else {
        session([
            'account_id'    => null,
            'building_id'   => null,
        ]);
    }

    return back();
```

Could anyone advise me how to find issue here

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper method here:

```
public function switchHeaders(Request $request) {
    $account = Account::find($request->get('account_id'));

    session([
        'account_id' => optional($account)->getKey(),
        'building_id' => optional($account)->getAttribute('building_id')
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

If `$account` in null, then the optional helper returns null from any chained function calls.

To further reduce the logic of the controller function, setup the route with an optional parameter for `$account`:

```
Route::get('switchHeaders/{account?}', 'AccountController@switchHeaders');
```

And explicitly bind the model in `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::bind('account', function ($value) {
    return \App\Account::find($value);
});
```

Which would reduce the controller function to:

```
public function switchHeaders(Request $request, $account = null) {
    session([
        'account_id' => optional($account)->getKey(),
        'building_id' => optional($account)->getAttribute('building_id')
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

Instead of passing in `account_id` as a form input, it would be part of the form's action:

```
// i.e. http://example.com/switchHeaders/1
<form action="switchHeaders/{{ $account->getKey() }}">
    ....
</form>
```

Comment: That does not fixes the issue however as for optimisation I found a lot, therefore thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to check two conditions in if condition. just modify your code like below and see if it works.

```
public function switchHeaders(Request $request) {

    $account = Account::find($request->account_id);

    if (!empty($account)) {

        session([
            'account_id'    => $account->id,
            'building_id'   => $account->building_id,
        ]);

    } else {
        session([
            'account_id'    => null,
            'building_id'   => null,
        ]);
    }

    return back();
```